# ( FAPI) Trouble Manipulating Managed Fields with Nested Field sets that can be added and removed dynamically

Tags: files, forms

So my problem is this. I am trying to create a configuration form that allows you to control the front end of a page display. On the front page there are these regions, and each regions holds text and a image that is set as a background. In addition to that each region can have multiple displays that will be randomly picked. what I don so far is add the ability for each display to be put in a fieldset, and each region to be put in a fieldset. Now displays can be added and remove from specific regions and regions can be added and removed from the form based on needs.

So my problem lies when I want to delete a region. I need the region that comes after it to take its place, but for some reason this deletes all images in the form, but text and other fields move fine.

My code is for the form is...

```
function MY_MODULE_configuration_page ($form, &$form_state) {

    // Allows you to debug deeply rooted arrays in form, Set to true if degub only shows last array of multidemntional array. 
    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;



    // Create a detailed associative array based on $scannedDirectoryResults. MY_MODULE_flattened_template_field_array() will return the $templateOptions array that will hold each template's details as well as an array suitible for select option field type located at $templateOptions['list']. 
    $templateOptions = array( '1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4', '5' => '5' );


    // Create an array of all the regions in the stored. 
    $region_fields;

    // If the form is rebuilt then the $region_fields needs to be rewritten to based on the current $form_state values
    if ($form_state['rebuild'] == TRUE && isset($form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['button_index']) && ($form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['button_index'] == 'add_item' || $form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['button_index'] == 'remove_item')) { 
        $region_fields['regions'] =  $form_state['values']['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'];     
    } else {
        $region_fields = variable_get('MY_MODULE_regions', array());
    }




    // set template option values
    $form['MY_MODULE_template_choices'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Selected'),
        '#options' => $templateOptions['list'], // The array generated from directory strucure. 
        '#default_value' => variable_get('MY_MODULE_template_choices'),
        '#description' => t('Select the style of <em>Yes</em> if you would like this category to be selected by default.'),
    );

    // Create a field set to hold all the regions. 
    $form['MY_MODULE_regions'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('regions'), 
        '#prefix' => '<div class="homepage-region">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>', 
    );




    $formNumOfRegions = $region_fields['element_count']; // pulled amount of elements stored in database

    // If form state is differnent from stored data replace with formstate.
    if ($form_state['rebuild'] == TRUE && isset($form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['button_index']) && ($form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['button_index'] == 'add_item' || $form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['button_index'] == 'remove_item')){
        $formNumOfRegions = $form_state['values']['MY_MODULE_regions']['element_count'];
    }


    // The number of regions that need to be created is maximum value between what the form currently has, what the template says needs, and there needs to be at least one. 
    $numOfRegions = max(1, $formNumOfRegions);


    // Set the element count to current element_count to equal $numOfRegions.
    $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['element_count'] = array('#type' => 'hidden', '#value' => $numOfRegions );


    // create the number of fieldsets (regions) necessary for form.  
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $numOfRegions; $i++) {

        $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$i] = array(
            '#type' => 'fieldset',
            '#title' => t('region-' . $i),
        );

        // determine the number of displays necessary
        $formNumOfDisplay = (isset($region_fields['regions'][$i]['element_count']))? $region_fields['regions'][$i]['element_count'] : 1 ;

        if ($form_state['rebuild'] == TRUE && isset($form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['button_index']) && ($form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['button_index'] == 'add_item' || $form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['button_index'] == 'remove_item')){
            $formNumOfDisplay = (isset($form_state['values']['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$i]['element_count']))?$form_state['values']['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$i]['element_count']:1;
        }

        // store the number of displays.
        $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$i]['element_count'] = array('#type' => 'hidden', '#value' => $formNumOfDisplay);

        // set the number of displays that needs to be created, at least one needs to be made. 
        $formNumOfDisplay = max(1, $formNumOfDisplay);

        for ($j = 1; $j <= $formNumOfDisplay; $j++) {


            $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j] = array(
                '#type' => 'fieldset',
                '#title' => t('display-' . $j), 
                '#prefix' => '<div class="display-region">',
                '#suffix' => '</div>', 
            );

            $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['cta'] = array(
                '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#title' => t('Call to action'),
                '#default_value' =>  $region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['cta'],
                '#description' => t('Main text display . <br/><br/>Limit of 30 characters.'),
                //'#value' => (!empty($region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['title'])) ? $region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['title'] : '',
            );

            $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['subtext'] = array(
                '#title' => t('Subtext'),
                '#type' => 'textarea',
                '#maxlength' => 150, 
                '#description' => t('Short description of region. <br/><br/>Limit of 150 character.'),
                '#default_value' => (!empty($region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['subtext']))
                        ? $region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['subtext']
                        : '',
                '#format' => 'filtered_html',
            );


            // Use the #managed_file FAPI element to upload an image file.
            $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['image_example_image_fid'.$i.$j] = array(
              '#title' => t('Image'),
              '#type' => 'managed_file',
              '#description' => t('<strong>Size Chart</strong><br/> <em>Mobile Image:</em> 800x600 pixels '),
              '#default_value' => (!empty($region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['image_example_image_mobile_fid'.$i.$j]))
                        ? $region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['image_example_image_mobile_fid'.$i.$j]
                        : '',
              // '#default_value' => variable_get('image_example_image_fid'.$i.$j, ''),
              '#upload_location' => 'public://image_example_images/',
            );

            $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['link'] = array(
              '#type' => 'link_field',
              '#field_name' => 'link_field',
              '#title' => t('Button link'),
              '#language' => 'und', // how to fix this??
              '#field_parents' => array(),
              '#delta' => 0,
              '#default_value' => array(
                  'title' => (!empty($region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['link']['title']))
                        ? $region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['link']['title']
                        : '',
                  'url' => (!empty($region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['link']['url']))
                        ? $region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['link']['url']
                        : '',
               ),
              '#description' => t('<strong>Title</strong><br/> Limited to 15 characters. <br/><br/> <strong>URL</strong><br/> <em>internal link:</em> ex. /path <br/> <em>external link:</em> ex. http://domain.ext  '),
            );

            $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['modal'] = array(

              '#type' =>'checkbox', 
              '#title' => t('Open Link in Modal window?'),
              '#description' => t('Click if you want to to open the link in a modal window.'),
              '#default_value' => (!empty($region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['modal']))
                        ? $region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['modal']
                        : null,
              '#return_value' => (!empty($region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['modal']))
                        ? $region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['modal']
                        : null,

            );

            $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['new_blank'] = array(

              '#type' =>'checkbox', 
              '#title' => t('Open Link in new window?'),
              '#description' => t('Click if you want to to open the link in a new tab.'),
              '#default_value' => (!empty($region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['new_blank']))
                        ? $region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['new_blank']
                        : null,
              '#return_value' => (!empty($region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['new_blank']))
                        ? $region_fields['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j]['new_blank']
                        : null,
            );



            $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$i]['displays'][$j][$i.'remove_item-display'] = array(
              '#type' => 'submit',
              '#value' => t('Region:' . $i . '-Remove Display ' .$j),
              '#submit' => array('MY_MODULE_remove_item'),
              '#prefix' => '<div class="form-button form-remove"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>',
              '#suffix' => '</div>',
              '#attributes' => array(
                'button_index' => 'remove_item',
                'parent_item' => 'display',
                'index_number' =>  $i,
                'display_number' =>  $j,
                'field_count' => $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$i]['element_count'],
              //'onclick' => 'if(!confirm("Deleting a region will save the form with current settings. \n\nIf you do not want to save yet, hit \"cancel\"; otherwise hit \"ok\". \n\ndo you want to continue?")){return false;}',
              ),
            );
        }

        $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$i]['add_item_display'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Add new display to region ' . $i),
            '#submit' => array('MY_MODULE_add_item'),
            '#prefix' => '<div class="clear-fix"><div class="form-button form-add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
            '#attributes' => array(
             'button_index' => 'add_item',
             'field_count' => $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$i]['element_count'],
            ),
        );

        $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$i]['remove_item_region'] = array(
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => t('Remove all of region ' . $i),
          '#submit' => array('MY_MODULE_remove_item'),
          '#prefix' => '<div class="form-button form-remove"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>',
          '#suffix' => '</div></div>',
          // '#submit' => array('MY_MODULE_remove_item'),
          '#attributes' => array(
            'button_index' => 'remove_item',
            'parent_item' => 'region',
            'index_number' =>  $i,
            'field_count' => $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['element_count'],
            //'onclick' => 'if(!confirm("Deleting a region will save the form with current settings. \n\nIf you do not want to save yet, hit \"cancel\"; otherwise hit \"ok\". \n\ndo you want to continue?")){return false;}',
          ),
          // Since we are removing a name, don't validate until later.
          // '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
        );
    }

    $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['add_item_region'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Add another region'),
        '#submit' => array('MY_MODULE_add_item'),
        '#prefix' => '<div class="form-button form-add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#attributes' => array(
         'button_index' => 'add_item',
         'field_count' => $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['element_count'],
        ),
    );



    $form['MY_MODULE_regions']['MY_MODULE_image'] = array(
      '#type' => 'media',
      '#title' => t('Hero background image'),
      '#default_value' => (!empty($region_fields['MY_MODULE_image']))
                        ? $region_fields['MY_MODULE_image']
                        : '',
    );

    // return(system_settings_form($form));

    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Save settings',
    );

   return $form;

}
```

My code form the add remove buttons are...

```
function MY_MODULE_add_item($form, &$form_state) {
    $i = $form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['field_count']['#value'];
    $i++;

    // Git Element Path
    $elementPathAsArray = $form_state['clicked_button']['#parents'];
    array_unshift($elementPathAsArray, "values"); 
    array_pop($elementPathAsArray);
    $elementPathAsArray[] = "element_count"; 


    $elementPathAsString = MY_MODULE_flatten_path($elementPathAsArray);

    MY_MODULE_set_array_value_from_keys($form_state, $elementPathAsString, $i);


    drupal_set_message(t("You added region a new display"), 'status');

    // ... and rebuild our form.
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function MY_MODULE_remove_item($form, &$form_state) {
    $i = $form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['field_count']['#value'];
    $i--;

    $areaToRemove = $form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['parent_item'];
    $areaName = $form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['index_number'];


    switch ($areaToRemove) {
        case "region":

            unset($form_state['values']['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$areaName]);
            unset($form_state['input']['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$areaName]);

            $keyCount =1;
            $tempArray = array();

            $form_state['values']['MY_MODULE_regions']['element_count'] = $i;
            foreach ($form_state['values']['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'] as $key => $val) {
                $tempArray[$keyCount] = $val;

                $keyCount++;
            }


            $form_state['values']['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'] = $tempArray;
            $form_state['input']['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'] = $tempArray;


            drupal_set_message(t("You removed region $areaName"), 'status');

            break;
        case "display":

            $dispayToRemove = $form_state['clicked_button']['#attributes']['display_number'];

            unset($form_state['values']['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$areaName]['displays'][$dispayToRemove]);
            unset($form_state['input']['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$areaName]['displays'][$dispayToRemove]);

            $keyCount =1;
            $tempArray = array();

            $form_state['values']['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$areaName]['element_count'] = $i;
            foreach ($form_state['values']['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$areaName]['displays'] as $key => $val) {
                $tempArray[$keyCount] = $val;
                $keyCount++;
            }

            $form_state['values']['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$areaName]['displays']  = $tempArray;
            $form_state['input']['MY_MODULE_regions']['regions'][$areaName]['displays']  = $tempArray;

            drupal_set_message(t("You removed Display $j in region $areaName"), 'status');

            break;
        default:

    }


    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;

}
```

Any help with why the images are not being moved like the other fields will be greatly appreciated.

Once again the functionality I need is for a region to replace the region before is it is removed. For example if 5 region page needs to be reduces we say the original template has regions 1,2,3,4,5 but we only want 1,2,4 we can easily delete region 3 and 5, but region 4 will automatically take 3's place.

here is a wireframe example of what we would see on the front end.

[image: 5 regions]

[image: three regions]